# IcCube - Treemap Chart with duplicate names

Tags: google-visualization, treemap, iccube-reporting

In the Google Treemap Chart every node has to have a unique id, but two nodes can have the same name (https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-visualization-api/UDLD-a-0PCM/IwVCGzsWOg8J).

I used the schema from the parent/child demo (http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/user_guide/schemas_cubes/dim_parentchild.php)

Using the following MDX statement in the treemap works, as long as the names of the nodes are unique:

```
WITH
  MEMBER [parent_name] as IIF( [dim (ALL)].[Hierarchy].currentmember 
  is  [dim (ALL)].[Hierarchy].[ALL],'',
  [dim (ALL)]. [Hierarchy].currentmember.parent.name )
SELECT
  {[parent_name],[Measures].[value]} on 0,
  non empty [dim (ALL)].[Hierarchy].members on 1
FROM
  [Cube]
```

If I added the line to the In-memory table in icCube's schema :

```
7,4,Spain, 2, 32
```

but the name Spain is double when rendering the Treemap. To support names a child definition in the GVI table should be something like this:

```
{v:'uniqueID-Spain', f:'Spain'}
```

Comment: how can you add a line ?

Comment: I added this line to the table in the schema and loaded the schema again.

Comment: If I understand the Treemap has nothing to do with the problem. I'm lost what/where is actually the problem ?

Comment: the in-memory table is using a comma to separate fields, not dot comma

Comment: I exchanged the comma for a semicolon in the whole table, to try to put this line like it is.

Comment: I change the text, I guess now it's a bit  clearer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround you can use the following code that modifies GviTable processing for the google tree widget. Check the example here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3kSph_LgXizSVhvSm15Q1hIdW8/view?usp=sharing

Report JavaScript:

```
function consumeEvent( context, event ) {
    if (event.name == 'ic3-report-init') {
        if(!_.isFunction(ic3.originalProcessGviTable)) {
            ic3.originalProcessGviTable = viz.charts.GenericGoogleWidget.prototype.processGviTable
        }

        viz.charts.GenericGoogleWidget.prototype.processGviTable = function(gviTable){
            if(this.props.ic3chartType === "TreeMap") {
                gviTable = gviTable || this.gviTable();
                var underlying = _.cloneDeep(gviTable.getUnderlyingGviTable());
                _.each(underlying.rows, function(row){
                    // Replace id with parent prefixed
                    if(_.isObject(row.c[0]) && !_.isString(row.c[0].f)) {
                        row.c[0].f = row.c[0].v;
                        if(_.isObject(row.c[0].p) && _.isString(row.c[0].p.mun)) {
                            row.c[0].v = row.c[0].p.mun;
                        }
                    }
                });
                gviTable = viz.GviTable.fromSnapshot(underlying);
                this.startColumnSelection = gviTable.getNumberOfHeaderColumns() - 1;
                return viz.charts.toGoogleDataTableOneRowHeader(gviTable);
            } else {
                return ic3.originalProcessGviTable.apply(this, gviTable);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For the query like:

```
WITH
  MEMBER [parent_name] as 
    IIF( [dim (ALL)].[Hierarchy].currentmember.isAll(),
        '', 
        ([dim (ALL)].[Hierarchy].currentmember.parent.uniqueName) 
    )
SELECT
  {[parent_name],[Measures].[value]} on 0,
  non empty [dim (ALL)].[Hierarchy].members on 1
FROM 
  [Cube]
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a limitation of Google Treemap chart that is using the same column for the id and the label. Besides changing the names to ensure they are unique (e.g. adding the parent) I don't see a workaround to this.

An option would be using another Treemap chart (e.g. one from D3) that has not this limitation.

--- icCube Schema ---

The schema is working (just use , instead of ; as separator ) 
[image]

--- icCube Reporting ---

The issue using Treemap is that you've two rows with the same id (Germany), [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t8w2446g/1/)

```
This fiddle is a running example of treemap
```

Comment: I edited your example and added the line " [{v:'7', f:'Germany'},    'America',            11,                              10],
         ". Now Germany is both under America and under Europe. Both is shown without problems. So it i not a limitation of the Google Treemap chart

Comment: Also from D3 only the Bullet Chart is shown in the reporting environment. So for using the treemap chart I probably need to implement something more, don't I?

Comment: For d3 yes, for your example , can you share a non working example in fiddle ?

Comment: Maybe there is a misunderstanding. I can show you a working example, where two nodes have the same name (Germany): https://jsfiddle.net/UlrichWuenstel/t8w2446g/ . My problem is, that I am not able to give this database via icCube to the chart.

Comment: I know that the schema is working as it is. Only if I want to put this data to the treemap chart, there is this problem with the double name. This is, why I asked, if it is possible in IcCube to put the data to the treemap chart as I showed in jsfiddle.

Comment: Eventually got it, without a transformation of the GVI table is not possible as the first column is the member definition (guess we could take the uniqueName). I think we need to change to code, let me check